# UITextView selection without becoming first responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

Previously the UITextView I added with IB could have text selected without having the keyboard appear. However suddenly without changing anything this is not the case, how can I force this behaviour again?

(The text view needs to be editable but not when the user double taps to select text, only when the caret is inserted or the user just taps on the textview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    NSRange selection = [yourTextView.text rangeOfString:yourTextView.text]; 
    if( selection.location != NSNotFound ){ yourTextView.selectedRange = selection; }
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: I don't want to select all the text, I want the user to be able to select any text without the keyboard appearing

Comment: @Jonathan. Than make yourTextView.editable =FALSE; This should do the trick you want. It will allow user to select text without appearing default keyboard.

Comment: @Jennis, but I need the text view to be editable, the user can hide the keyboard to get more room and then select text.

Comment: @Jonathan. So you mean to say User is able to write some text in UITextView and though keyboard should be hidden ? Is this what you want ?

Comment: @Jennis, No The keyboard is visible, the user enters text, the user presses the hide button, the keyboard hides. The user then selects part of the text without the keyboard reappearing

Comment: @Jonathan. That is possible with yourTextView.editable =FALSE. User can select text easily with that. If you want it to have editable afterwards have a button which provides user to enable/disable keyboard appearance. i.e. yourTextView.editable = UserSelectedOption. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jennis, I thought I'd have to do that, but I'd prefer it if the keyboard appears on one tap, and selection is done on 2 taps. Also it worked how I needed it before without any modification

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very simple. just make textview editable false before selecting the text so that testview never get responder. and then  use the above code to get selected text